# How to evaluate regexs on sed style

Tags: python

Let's suppose that user input is:

```
s/foo/bar
```

and the string is

```
the foo is
```

the output on sed will be `the bar is`, right?

So, using the `re` module, how can I achive this in pure python?

Answer (score 1):

With `re.sub` and simple `str.replace` (use the latter one for simple sub-string substitutions to avoid any extra overhead incurred via regex):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("foo", "bar", "the foo is")
'the bar is'
>>> "the foo is".replace("foo", "bar")
'the bar is'
```

It seems you want to replace only the first occurrence (since for replacing every occurrence, the sed pattern would be `s/foo/bar/g`), you can replace only the first `foo` by `bar` like this:

```
>>> re.sub("foo", "bar", "the foo is foo", 1)
'the bar is foo'
>>> "the foo is foo".replace("foo", "bar", 1)
'the bar is foo'
```

Comment: I was looking for something more like what sed does. I can use the library `sh`, but first I am looking for a pure python solution. Thanks for your time